# Firebase notification not recieved when app is swiped away from task manager

Tags: php, android

I am using google firebase its working for some of the devices but when it is swiped away from background i don't receive the notification.I am new to android don't know how to solve the issue.
Please suggest some solutions for this.

Comment: u mean some devices are able to receive, even when it is swiped away from recent apps menu??

Comment: Yes some are able to receive and some of them don't.